# Why does my Cassandra Lucene Index returns less/ no results from 2 queries?

Tags: cassandra, lucene

Since I constantly have this problem described below I would like to change but lack of a better alternative.

I have 2 queries which should return the same result. But the 2nd query returns a lot less results or sometimes no results. These are the 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3';
SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE source = 'toutiao' AND timespan = '3'   AND text = '{ sort: {fields: [{field: "speed", reverse: true}]}}';.
```

I use this custom cassandra index https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index.

I use Cassandra 2.2.4.1 cassandra-lucene-index 2.2.4

'text' is the table column over which I have built the index.

My Index creation query is:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX statistics_text_idx ON toutiao.statistics (text) USING 'com.stratio.cassandra.lucene.Index' WITH OPTIONS = {'schema': '{
        fields : {
            title: {
                                type : "text", analyzer : "english"},
                                category : {type:"string"},
                genre : {type:"string"},
                speed  : {type : "integer",sorted : true}
        }
}', '
        refresh_seconds': '1'};
```

Table creation query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statistics;
CREATE TABLE statistics (
source text,
timespan text,
id text,
title text,
thumbnail text,
url text,
text text,
created_at timestamp,
category text,
category2 text,
genre text,
author text,
reads int,
likes int,
comments int,
shares int,
speed int,
PRIMARY KEY (source, timespan, id)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timespan DESC) AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}';
```

This is my data insert program:

```
cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])
session_statis = cluster.connect(keyspace)
session_statis.execute('INSERT INTO tablename(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15) values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5,value6,value7,value8,value9,value10,value11,value12,value13,value14,value15))
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: How are you inserting you datas? I had the same problem and turns out it was because of the SSTable loader

Comment: @Will I added my data inserting program in the post above. What was your solution? thanks